# Reset UIProgressView After Animation is Complete

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, swift2, ios9

I want to reset (set progress to 0) my UIProgressView after the following code:

```
// uploadProgress: UIProgressView!

uploadProgress.progress = 0
uploadProgress.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
```

I can't set uploadProgress.progress to 0 right after this block because then no animation will appear.

I don't want to edit the animation duration either.

I just want the progress to go back to 0 **AFTER** the animation is **fully complete**.

I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but I came across the same problem and this is how I solve it. Since the animation on the `UIProgressView` is done on the layer, we can use `CATransaction`'s completion block to capture when the animation has ended.

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
   // do whatever you want when the animation is completed
   self.progressBar.hidden = true
})
self.progressBar.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the animation UIView.animate function with the completion handler.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.progressBar.setProgress(1, animated: true)
}, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
    progressBar.progress = 0
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This certainly helps. Now the problem is that it animates too quick. Even if I set the duration to like 1000 the animation duration does not change. It stays really quick. UIView.animateWithDuration(1000, animations: {
                        self.uploadProgress.progress = 1
                        }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                            self.uploadProgress.progress = 0
                    })